# Small Tabs appear using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to create multiple tabs with fragment for each tab.
I have managed that but the two tabs appear at the corner of the layout.
I'm unable to divide the width of the tab layout equally to the tabs.
The code :
activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    style = "MyCustomTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code : FragmentPagerAdapter

```
    public class Frag_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT =2;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
private Context ccontext;

public Frag_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int i)
{
    switch (i) {
        case 0: return new MyFrag();
        case 1: return new MyFrag1();
        default: return null;
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Add `app:tabGravity="fill"` to your TabLayout xml if you want distribute all available space to each tab.

Change `app:tabMode="scrollable"` in your TabLayout xml to `app:tabMode="fixed"`
if you want all your tabs to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `tabMode` attribute of `TabLayout` to `fixed` instead of `scrollable`, so the tabs would take all available space and have their width the same, based on the largest one as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#MODE_FIXED).